# Algorithm to generate all possible combinations of 0s & 1s, for any length of digits

Tags: algorithm

I would like to know how can I print n number of combinations of 1s and 0s. The number of combinations, `n` is user defined. The expected outputs are;

n=1;

```
0,1
```

n=2;

```
00,01,10,11
```

n=3;

```
000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111
```

etc.. etc..

The outputs will have `2^n` number of combinations (where n is the number of expected digits in a single combination).

How can I do this without using any built in function? The question is language independent and is for algorithm.

Comment: why -1? the question is genuine and is 'on' topic

Comment: important remark: you are actually talking about permutations and not about combinations!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could just enumerate all numbers till `2^n - 1` in binary. That will leave you with the same combination.

`n = 2` enumerate till `2^3 - 1` = `7`
Convert to binary:

```
000 --> 0
001 --> 1
010 --> 2
011 --> 3
100 --> 4
101 --> 5
110 --> 6
111 --> 7
```

**EDIT**: Fixed the number of digits as well. This works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 3
void print_binary(int n)
{
        int bit = 1<<LENGTH - 1;
        while ( bit ) {
        printf("%d", n & bit ? 1 : 0);
        bit >>= 1;
        }
        printf("\n");
}
int main(){
    int n = 1<<LENGTH, i; 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        print_binary(i);
}
```

Comment: can you please post an example, working in C without using any special built in function?

Comment: if thats the case, i think 0,1,10,11 will be printed instead of 000,001,010 and 011

Comment: no it's not.  you can pre-append 0 as needed to get the right length.  you asked for an algorithm, he gave you an algorithm.  why don't you just implement it yourself?!

Comment: replace the first for loop with n=(1<<LENGTH);

Comment: @thang Much better :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not care about speed and memory, you cold use recursion which leads to a small and short solution:

```
public static void print01PermutationsUpToLength(final String currentString, final int upTo) {
    if (upTo == 0) {
        System.out.println(currentString);
        return;
    }
    print01PermutationsUpToLength(currentString + "0", upTo - 1);
    print01PermutationsUpToLength(currentString + "1", upTo - 1);
}
```

(java. Obviously, this could be done in every language which allows recursion and call-by-value or copy of String)

If you do not like the `String` argument, you could add a start function:

```
public static void print01PermutationsUpToLength(final int upTo) {
    print01PermutationsUpToLength("", upTo);
}
```

results:

```
final int upToLength = 3;
print01PermutationsUpToLength(upToLength);
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Formatting can be changed like you want, this was only to see the results better.
Ordering can be changed if you switch the parts of the String construction (`currentString + "0"`).

Answer (score 2):

```
void print_digit(int n,int digits)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<digits;i++)
   { 
       if(n&(1<<(digits-i-1)))
       {
           putchar('1');
       }
       else
       {
           putchar('0');
       }
   }
}

print all_digits(int e)
{
   for(i=0;i<(1<<e);i++)
   {
        print_digit(i,e);
        putchar('\n');
   }
   fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: i don't think you need (e+1).  just n is ok.

Comment: e is like exponent. Input value is power like 3 or 4

Comment: yea but if all_digits(1) is called, you output twice as many strings as needed.  i guess it's ok.  just not what's asked.

Answer (score 0):

This is my view to this problem.Given an array of characters and you want to find the k combination of that using the entire array.
To address this question our Array contains : `['0','1']`.

Let's say we have a `char set[] = new {'0','1'};`

Below method will give you any number of combination of zero and one. I have testing it with combination of 0 and 1 with dataset of 50 characters.

```
public  void printLengthRec(char[] inputSet, String prefix, int k) {
    int sizeOfInputArray=inputSet.length;
    //TerminationCase: k is 0, print prefix
    if (k == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
        return;
    }    
    // One by one add all characters from set and recursively 
    // call for k equals to k-1
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        // Next character of input added
        String newPrefix = prefix + set[i]; 
        printLengthRec(inputSet, newPrefix, k - 1); 
    }
}
```