# PHP - Get all possibilities of three digits that can be either 0 or 1

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I'm a bit stuck on a math/algorithm question. I have three digits that can be either 0 or 1. Now i need to generate a PHP array containing all possibilities without duplicates. e.g.

```
000
001
010
100
011
101
...
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: anything you have tried ? share your code too

Comment: My bad. I though of answering this one but found [\[ this \]](http://psoug.org/snippet/Permutation_Generator_384.htm) off-the-shelf solution pretty tempting. There is a search engine called [\[ google\]](https://google.com) where you could have searched first before putting this one here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i=0; $i <= 7; $i++)
 echo str_pad(decbin($i), 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT) . "\n";
```

[demo](https://eval.in/598941)

Comment: Sorry for my not understanding but where is the 7 coming from? :)

Comment: three variables with 0 or 1 value - max value is 7

Comment: @n00b is my explanation not enough?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how any prebuilt functions that could be used, but a general solution can be that, if you know exactly how many/what digits you need, you can do that fairly easily with a triple for loop, each going from 0 to 1 and each "controlling" one of the 3 digits. Something like:

```
for($i=0; $i<2; $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<2; $j++){
        for($k=0; $k<2; $k++)
            $array[$i+$j+$k]=$i+$j*10+$k*100;
    }
}
```

PS: wrote that in literally 20 secs so there might be a small mistake, to be checked ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define LENGTH 3
    void print_binary(int n)
    {
            int bit = 1<<LENGTH - 1;
            while ( bit ) {
            printf("%d", n & bit ? 1 : 0);
            bit >>= 1;
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    int main(){
        int n = 1<<LENGTH, i; 
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            print_binary(i);
    }
```

[More Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632555/algorithm-to-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-0s-1s-for-any-length-of-di)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array();
for ($i=0; $i <= 7; $i++)
 $arr[] = str_pad(decbin($i), 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

?>
```

Hope this solves your issue.